# Magento 2.3.2 Elasticsearch issue with multi language(Greek)

Tags: search, elasticsearch, magento2.3.2

I am using Elasticsearch 6.8.1 with magento 2.3.2 instance.
Although in English store my search is working fine, in Greek store I am having some issues with the words having accents. This happens only if Elasticsearch is used. With mysql everything is fine

Example:

> room in Greek is "δωμάτιο"
>
> notice "ά" letter has an accent

If you search:

> "δωμ" you get right results including names with "δωμάτιο"(room)

But if you search:

> "δωμάτιο" or "δωμάτιο" or "δώμα"

You don't get any result with this word at all.

**The accent in the letter "α" breaks the search.**

I tried to put the letter with accents as a synonym but no luck.

Anyone with same issues please?

It is very annoying because it breaks search and make it not good for customers

Answer (score 0):

Try below custom code by creating a custom module. The below code based on ES 6.8.x and Magento 2.3 version.

**Custom\Grek\etc\di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\Index\Builder">
        <plugin name="custom_grek_custom_builder" type="Custom\Grek\Plugin\Model\Adapter\Index\CustomBuilder"></plugin>
</type>
```

**Custom\Grek\Plugin\Model\Adapter\Index\CustomBuilder.php**

```
<?php
namespace Check\Grek\Plugin\Model\Adapter\Index;

class CustomBuilder {

    public function afterBuild(\Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\Index\Builder $subject, $result)
    {
        $greekToken = $this->getGreekTokenizer();
        $result['analysis']['tokenizer'] = $greekToken;
        $result['analysis']['filter']['trigrams_filter'] = [
            'type' => 'ngram',
            'min_gram' => 3,
            'max_gram' => 3
        ];
        $result['analysis']['analyzer']['my_analyzer'] = [
            'type' => 'custom',
            'tokenizer' => 'standard',
            'filter' => [
                'lowercase', 'trigrams_filter'
            ]
        ];
        return $result;
    }


    protected function getGreekTokenizer()
    {
        $tokenizer = [
            'default_tokenizer' => [
                'type' => 'ngram'
            ],
        ];
        return $tokenizer;
    }
}
```

Magento 2 indexers required to rebuild after applied so mapping can be updated as well.